# Finding the Lengths of Two Radii of Overlapping Circles

Tags: geometry

Circles $O$ and $P$ are given as shown in the diagram. The perimeter $\triangle AOP$$ =54$, $OC +DP=16$, and $CD$ is 2 units longer than $OC$. How can I determine the sum of $OB+BP$?Any guidance or solutions would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: OAP looks a right triangle... any information about that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooh that's a fun setup!

I would start by writing every single side in terms of the three lengths OC, CD and DP.  Let's say $x=OC, y=CD, z=DP$.  Then we have $AO=OD=x+y$, $OP=x+y+z$, $AP=CP=y+z$.  So we have $(x+y) + (y+z) + (x+y+z) = 54$, $x+z=16$, and $y = x + 2$. That's three equations in three variables.  Can you solve that?

And for the sum you're asked to provide, $OB=OD=x+y, BP=CP=y+z$ so don't forget to calculate the sum for your answer instead of the values of $x, y, z$.

Comment: I've gone through and checked this works.  $x, y, z$ are all fractions with denominator 3, but the answer itself is a nice integer.  Though it also made me realize there's a shorter way to do this than solving for all 3.